# Structure query builder generated SQL statement? Multiple joins to the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here's the use case for this:

> Get me a list of heats where element #18 is between 95 and 100 AND element #2 is between 0.0 and 0.5.

This works just fine (not sure it's the best SQL/approach, but it works).

The question/potential problem is that *the number of element/range conditions is variable*.  The user is constructing a query to find records that meet a variety of element/range conditions.

```
SELECT v.*
FROM heats v  
INNER JOIN chem c ON v.HeatSheetID = c.HeatSheetID AND c.PrimaryARS = 1 
LEFT JOIN ElementValues ev ON c.AnalysisNo = ev.AnalysisNo 
LEFT JOIN ElementValues ev1 ON c.AnalysisNo = ev1.AnalysisNo 
WHERE  
(ev.ElementID = 18 AND ev.ElementValue BETWEEN 95 AND 100) 
AND (ev1.ElementID = 2 AND ev1.ElementValue BETWEEN 0.0 AND 0.5)
```

Is there a better way to structure this type of query?

--EDIT--
Here's a portion of the UI that the user is using:

[image]

Each 'heat' record has up to 25 elements associated with it (these are stored in the elementvalue table).

```
CREATE TABLE 
[dbo].[ElementValues](
    [AnalysisNo] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ElementID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [ElementValue] [decimal](7, 4) NULL

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[chem](
    [AnalysisNo] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [AnalysisDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [Quality] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DTImported] [datetime] NULL,
    [HeatSheetID] [int] NULL,
    [PrimaryARS] [bit] NULL,
    [RecStatus] [bit] NULL
```

Sample Data in ElementValues

[image]

Sample data in chem table

[image]

Comment: Define better? If you gives you the desired results, what are you attempting to improve? Although looking at it, your query doesn't appear to work? You are joining on `c.AnalysisNo` and expecting the elementid to be both 18 *and* 2? Thats not going to happen. You need to add sample data and expected results that illustrate the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Perhaps 'better' isn't the correct term.  If the user chooses 10 different elements, do I just join to the ElementValues table 10 times?  I guess I'm thinking that would be impractical and/or inefficient.  Is there a different way in SQL to accomplish this?

Comment: Looks like you need a Table-Valued Parameter and do relational division on it

Comment: Perhaps [intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/all-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) might be useful? It is difficult to understand the tables and how they are used. A script containing DDL and sample data would be very useful and encouraging.

Comment: Users are using the application UI to "construct" the query which then is being translated in code into the appropriate SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does really depend on how you are building the query.... I would probably use `exists` and you can easily add a new `exists` condition matched to the users selections.

```
SELECT v.*
FROM heats v  
INNER JOIN chem c ON v.HeatSheetID = c.HeatSheetID AND c.PrimaryARS = 1 
WHERE 1 = 1
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ElementValues ev WHERE c.AnalysisNo = ev.AnalysisNo AND ev.ElementID = 18 AND ev.ElementValue BETWEEN 95 AND 100)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ElementValues ev WHERE c.AnalysisNo = ev.AnalysisNo AND ev.ElementID = 2 AND ev.ElementValue BETWEEN 0.0 AND 0.5)
-- ...
```

I imagine it will perform pretty much the same as what you have, but it should be a touch easier to build the query from the user input.

Comment: This is what I meant by "better".  :-)  Thanks!